# Can't hit the DB, by integration testing with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, omniauth, minitest

I keep getting test F

> "User.count" didn't change by 1.

even if I should not (because SessionsController#create really works already).

Testing code is like this :

**- [REFACTORED/UPDATED] -** 
I also dropped off all validation in the models, just to see ... but nothing

```
class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "valid signup information" do   

    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = false

    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      get '/auth/identity/register', params: {
        user: { name: "Example User",
                email: "user@example.com",
                password_digest: "password",
                identities: { user_id: 1, 
                              provider: "identity", 
                              uid: "1"}}}
    end

    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  end
end
```

The full output:

```
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information = 0.69 s = F


Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information [/home/lsoave/rails5/gitwatcher/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:19]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 5
  Actual: 4
```

with `tail -f log/test.log` I get the following:

```
----------------------------------------------
UsersSignupTest: test_valid_signup_information
----------------------------------------------
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 15:17:16 +0100
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (37.7ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_signup-modal.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 265ms (Views: 250.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
Started GET "/auth/identity/register?user[name]=Example+User&user[email]=user%40example.com&user[password_digest]=[FILTERED]&user[identities][user_id]=1&user[identities][provider]=identity&user[identities][uid]=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 15:17:16 +0100
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

**UPDATE NOTE:**

The real model is User has_many identities / Identity belong_to user relationship, I'm not sure it is correctly represented by :

```
...
params: {
            user: { name: "Example User",
                    email: "user@example.com",
                    password_digest: "password",
                    identities: { user_id: 1, 
                                  provider: "identity", 
                                  uid: "1"}}}
...
```

Comment: Maybe one of the validations of your User model is not passing.

Comment: @gabrielef I also dropped off all validation in the models, just to see ... but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the identities: piece with something like:

```
identities_attributes: { '0': {provider: "identity", uid: "1"}}
```

and check your User model contains:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :identities
```

No need to deal yourself with assigning user_id to the dependent model, that is what Rails is good at.